# Which procedures/functions/views refer to a particular table

Tags: sql, reference

I have a table and would like to know which all procedures/views/functions refer to that table. How do I do that in SQL?

Comment: what rdbms are you working with?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MS SQL:

```
SELECT 
    referencing_schema_name, referencing_entity_name, referencing_id, 
    referencing_class_desc, is_caller_dependent
FROM 
    sys.dm_sql_referencing_entities ('mySchemaName.myTableName', 'OBJECT');
GO
```

Replace mySchemaName and myTableName with your actual schema name and table name and run the above query